# How to Make ListViews scroll together

Tags: android, listview, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am developing an app in Flutter. I have a screen that has a schedule. I want it to scroll both horizontally and vertically. How can I make all the list viewers scroll vertically together?

[Screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RIxO.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
Widget daysContainer() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (1- 0.15),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              for(int i = 0 ; i < daysList.length ; i ++)
                dayContainer(i),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget dayContainer(int i){
    Color color1;
    Color color2;

    if((i%2) != 0){
      color1= Color.fromARGB(255,240,240,240);
      color2= Color.fromARGB(255,250,250,250);
    }
    else{
      color2= Color.fromARGB(255,240,240,240);
      color1= Color.fromARGB(255,250,250,250);
    }
    finalBlock=0;

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          dayHeaderContainer(i, color1),
          blockContainer(i, color2),
        ],
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      color: color2,
      width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15)) * 0.3333,
    );
  }

Widget blockContainer(int i, Color color) {
return Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
  color: color,
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      for(int j = 0; j < widget.talkList.length; j++)
        if(daysList[i].day == widget.talkList[j].dateInitial.day && widget.talkList[j].selected)
          individualTalkBlock(i, j, color, Color.fromARGB(255,247,220,222)),

    ],
  ),
);}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried looking at this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/bidirectional_scroll_view#-readme-tab-)? BTW, with what you are trying to achieve, instead of `ListView`s, I'd recommend you using `GestureDetector` to fully enable/animate the behaviour you want to achieve.  Please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833003/multidirectional-scroll-in-flutter).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! I was able to make it work with the second link with an exception: I want the top row to be fixed vertically: when I scroll vertically I want the top to be fixed. I was able to fixed first column horizontally putting it outside the SingleChildScrollView for scrolling horizontally. Any sugestions?