# How to constraints width and height of `Scaffold` (useful for Web and Desktop)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The screenshot below is a `Scaffold` on Desktop (should be similar on browser):

[image]

Is it possible to constraints `Scaffold` to a min size (width and height)?

If screen width is smaller than the min width, a horizontal scrollbar appears to move left and right.

If screen height is smaller than the min height, a vertical scrollbar appears to move up and down.

Ex. designers in our project want a min width of 960px on browser.

Comment: You can use layout builder and have a custom responsive class that renders different widgets according to constraint you give.

Comment: Could you please give me a draft code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example main.dart that uses `LayoutBuilder` to constrain the scaffold (both the body and the appBar) to a min of 480dp, and if the width constraints are less than that, wraps the scaffold inside a horizontal `ScrollView` with a `ScrollBar`. And if the constraint height is less than 480dp, it wraps scaffold (which may already be wrapped or not) in a vertical scroll.

If both width and height are less than 480dp, 2 scrollbars are visible. In this case, the widget tree must be `ScrollBar > ScrollBar > ScrollView > ScrollView`. If widget tree is `ScrollBar > ScrollView > ScrollBar > ScrollView`, the nested Scrollbar is only visible when the parent ScrollBar is scrolled to the edge side.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    // set default isAlwaysShown, so don't need to set for individual Scrollbar.
    theme: ThemeData(scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(isAlwaysShown: true)),
    home: App(),
  ));
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AppState createState() => AppState();
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  final minWidth = 480.0;
  final minHeight = 480.0;

  ScrollController _horizontalController = ScrollController();
  ScrollController _verticalController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _horizontalController.dispose();
    _verticalController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildScaffold() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('2D Scrollbars')),
      body: Container(color: Colors.amber),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: 'School'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final scaffold = _buildScaffold();
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final horizontalScrollbarEnabled = constraints.minWidth < minWidth;
        final verticalScrollbarEnabled = constraints.minHeight < minHeight;

        if (horizontalScrollbarEnabled && verticalScrollbarEnabled) {
          return Scrollbar(
            controller: _horizontalController,
            child: Scrollbar(
              // IMPORTANT: this scrollbar only handle notification of the vertical ScrollView.
              // The first ScrollView (depth = 0), is the horizontal one.
              // The second ScrollView (depth = 1), is the vertical one.
              // If notification.depth != 1, the notification is bubble up to horizontal Scrollbar.
              notificationPredicate: (notification) => notification.depth == 1,
              controller: _verticalController,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _horizontalController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _verticalController,
                  child: Container(
                    width: minWidth,
                    height: minHeight,
                    child: scaffold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (horizontalScrollbarEnabled) {
          return Scrollbar(
            controller: _horizontalController,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _horizontalController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Container(
                width: minWidth,
                child: scaffold,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (verticalScrollbarEnabled) {
          return Scrollbar(
            controller: _verticalController,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _verticalController,
              child: Container(
                height: minHeight,
                child: scaffold,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }

        return scaffold;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @benjamin-lee!
It works for horizontal constraint.
I am trying to make it works also for vertical constraint.

Comment: @XuanDaiNguyen, I edited my answer so it uses both horizontal and vertical scroll

Comment: I accepted your answer because it solves exactly the original question.  

Now if I want to add `isAlwaysShown: true` to `Scrollbar`, it requires to have a `ScrollController` to use for both `Scrollbar` and `SingleChildScrollView`. So far so good.  

When expand screen from smaller (with scrollbar) to bigger (without scrollbar), I get error:  
`The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 108 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'`

Comment: See: https://dartpad.dev/82ae28f3e792c6c8ef0ae6602c3888d1?null_safety=true

Comment: Beside the error above, there is another issue with nested `Scrollbar`.
In your example, the vertical scrollbar is nested in the horizontal one.
this vertical scrollbar is visible only when scroll to right edge.

Comment: You need to start locally in your local browser or start with desktop version. Dartpad doesn't show the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232357/discussion-between-benjamin-lee-and-xuan-dai-nguyen).

Comment: Depending on how picky your client is you may want to try a solution like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833003/multidirectional-scroll-in-flutter and write the scrollbars yourself. But this would be a lot of work.

Comment: I am leaving the 2 problems there for now. I think the better solution is to wait for https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64210

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70380

Comment: I edited your code to fixed the nested scrollbar issue.